# Makefile to compile both C and Java programs at the same time

Tags: java, c, makefile, compilation

I have three programs that need to be compiled at the same time, 2 written in C and 1 in java.  I had all three working with the Makefile when they were in C, but then rewrote one of them in java... is there a way to compile all 3 at once with the same makefile?

Here is my current Makefile:

```
CC=gcc 
JC=javac 
JFLAGS= -g
CFLAGS= -Wall -g -std=c99
LDFLAGS= -lm
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
 $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = kasiski.java kentry.java

ALL= ic ftable kasiski

all: $(ALL)

ic: ic.o

kasiski: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

ftable: ftable.o

ic.o: ic.c ic.h

ftable.o: ftable.c ftable.h

.PHONY: clean

clean:
 rm -rf core* *.class *.o *.gch $(ALL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can compile them all at once. If your "all" target depends on all three applications, then "make all" should build all of them. You can throw in "-j3" to actually compile using three separate threads and/or processes (it isn't clear what you mean by "at once"). Also, a couple criticisms here:

- Do not define "CC", "CFLAGS", or "LDFLAGS". You should never define "CC" as it is automatically defined for you to the default C compiler on the system, and you should merely append to "CFLAGS" and "LDFLAGS" as needed (using +=) instead of clobbering them, as simply assigning to them makes your Makefile inflexible (because they cannot be overrided or augmented externally).
- Using CLASSES to refer to ".java" files is confusing as hell... you should probably rename the variable to JAVA_SRCS, and define JAVA_CLASSES=${JAVA_SRCS:.java=.class}.

For more explanation, please see my [Makefile tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile). That said, you may want to consider a more modern build system such as [Bazel](http://bazel.io/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). These systems are designed to be much simpler to use, less error prone, more portable (because they make it easier to do things portably), and faster.

Comment: Removing the "CC" line solved the problem... although I also had files "kasiski.c" and "kasiski.h" (from a previous C attempt at the project) which caused a lot of noise and errors from make (I still can't figure out why).  After deleting those source files, it compiled everything without a hitch. Thanks!

Comment: @ Michael: https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/how-to-guides/how-to-write-a-makefile

page not found 
provide the new link

Comment: Sorry, it had moved to https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile a while ago and I didn't realize that there were still dead links like this. Updated.